# How to convert Byte[] to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I need help, I have this method to get a BitmapImage from a Byte[]

```
public BitmapSource ByteToBitmapSource(byte[] image)
{
    BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image))
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        imageSource.BeginInit();
        imageSource.StreamSource = stream;
        imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        imageSource.EndInit();
    }

    return imageSource;
}
```

`imageSource.EndInit();` throws an error "We found no imaging component suitable to complete this operation."

Comment: What format is the image you're trying to load? Are you sure it's supported?

Answer (score 27):

Set `Image.Source` to a byte array property in XAML.

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding Path=MyByteArrayProperty}" />
```

If you *really* want you can do this in code-behind:

```
public void DecodePhoto(byte[] byteVal)
{
  BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
  myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
  myBitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(byteVal);
  myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
  myBitmapImage.EndInit();
  MyImage.Source = myBitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: How can you set Image.Source to a byte[] when it's of type ImageSource?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us with more info on your image.
I can assume it's unsupported by the system, which I would then advice you to use an external tool, such as [imageMagik](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or any other converter specific to your image.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar, but it's not with BitmapImage, hopes it can help...

First, I get the image from a path, so I get a BMP and cast into a byte[]:

```
private byte[] LoadImage(string szPathname)
  {
     try
     {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(szPathname, true);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
     }catch (Exception){...}

     return null;
  }
```

I call this in my code like this:

```
byte[] bitmapData1 = LoadImage(@"C:\Users\toto\Desktop\test1.bmp");
```

And when I want to cast the byte[] into System.Windows.Controls.Image I do this:

```
protected virtual void OnByteArrayChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        // PropertyChanged method
        BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
        bmpi.BeginInit();
        bmpi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ByteArray);
        bmpi.EndInit();

        System.Windows.Controls.Image image1 = (get my image in my xaml);
        image1.Source = bmpi;
     }catch (Exception){...}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;


public class MakeBitmapSource
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory")]
    public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, uint Length);



    public static BitmapSource FromNativePointer(IntPtr pData, int w, int h, int ch)
    {
        PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Default;

        if (ch == 1) format = PixelFormats.Gray8; //grey scale image 0-255
        if (ch == 3) format = PixelFormats.Bgr24; //RGB
        if (ch == 4) format = PixelFormats.Bgr32; //RGB + alpha


        WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, format, null);
        CopyMemory(wbm.BackBuffer, pData, (uint)(w * h * ch));

        wbm.Lock();
        wbm.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, wbm.PixelWidth, wbm.PixelHeight));
        wbm.Unlock();

        return wbm;
    }

    public static BitmapSource FromArray(byte[] data, int w, int h, int ch)
    {
        PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Default;

        if (ch == 1) format = PixelFormats.Gray8; //grey scale image 0-255
        if (ch == 3) format = PixelFormats.Bgr24; //RGB
        if (ch == 4) format = PixelFormats.Bgr32; //RGB + alpha


        WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(w, h, 96, 96, format, null);
        wbm.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, w, h), data, ch * w, 0);

        return wbm;
    }
}
```