# Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Windows.Controls.Image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Ok, there is countless from byte to String and etc, but i simply can't find anything on how i can convert the resource files visual studio so nicely convert into a byte[] for me no matter what i do, into a normal Image so i can actually use it in my C# code?

Comment: Show your codezzzzz..

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=byte+array+to+image+c%23

Comment: This *basically* relates to this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897210/byte-to-bitmapimage - just set the `Source` on your `Image` to the `BitmapImage` once done

Answer (score 1):

You can use a valueconverter to do this -

```
public class InMemoryImageValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value);
        image.SetSource(memoryStream);
        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
        return null;
    }
}
```

adapted from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsPhone/MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter.cs#L17

then you can use that in the Image control as

```
<Image Source="{Binding TheBytes, Converter={StaticResource InMemoryImage}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if your image is resource of the application then you can do as following

```
Uri uriR = new Uri("/WP7SampleProject3;component/images/appbar.feature.email.rest.png", UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage imgSourceR = new BitmapImage(uriR);
this.imageR.Source = imgSourceR;
```

- [WP7 working with Images: Content vs Resource build action](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action)